# PHP - mpdf and output buffering couldn't work inside a function

Tags: php, function, pdf, include, mpdf

I am using mpdf to generate pdf file using output buffering. There is no problem of generating pdfs outside the function. The problem is, it couldn't generate a pdf inside a function. No pdf file is generated. The data to be included in the pdf is image files in the foreach loop below.

```
include("search/mpdf/mpdf.php");
function generatecont ($firstdate, $seconddate, $allfiles) {
  echo '<div class="displayoutput" style="display:none;">';
  echo "<a href='data/pdf/".$_GET["parameter"].'-'.$firstdate .'-'. $seconddate. '.pdf' ."'>Download PDF </a>"; 
 //include("search/mpdf/mpdf.php");
  global $html;
  global $mpdf;
  $mpdf=new mPDF();
  ob_start(); 
  foreach ($allfiles as $filesfound) {  
      echo '<h1 class="displaytitle">'.strtoupper(substr(basename($filesfound), 0,-4)). '</h1>';
      echo '<div class="visualize">'.'<img src="'. $filesfound. '"></div>';
  }
  $html = ob_get_contents();
  ob_get_flush();
  $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
  $mpdf->Output('data/pdf/'.$_GET["parameter"].'-'.$firstdate .'-'. $firstdate. '.pdf','F');
  echo '</div>';
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify your question? What is the issue? What is showing up onscreen? What is the function generatecont() supposed to return?

Comment: Thank you. I have updated my question. The function is supposed to generate the pdf and other contents. Is it clear now?

Comment: I would check permissions as a start, and any output/log messages. Also, the link generated in the first part uses `$seconddate` but the file being saved near the end uses `$firstdate` twice. So the file being generated is not the same as the file being linked.

Comment: Very nice observation! It is solved now when I corrected the file name to be generated. Thank you! Please post it as an answer.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks! Have added it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check permissions as a start, and any output/log messages. Also, the link generated in the first part uses `$seconddate` but the file being saved near the end uses `$firstdate` twice. So the file being generated is not the same as the file being linked.